# What registrars can I use to transfer a .co.uk domain?

Tags: domains

I am taking over a .co.uk domain from another party and need a reputable registrar.  Network Solutions and Godaddy both state they can't handle .co.uk domains. What other reputable registrars can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://www.123-reg.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

See the [NIC.uk List of Registrars](http://www.nic.uk/registrars/becomeregistrar/taglist/) for a long list of registrars who offer domains under the `.uk` top-level domain.